# Save data in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to create a game that counts the clicks made in 60 seconds and saves the record. I would like this record to be saved on the device even after the app is closed. Is there some kind of variable that allows me to do this?

Comment: Look up shared preferences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android's Shared Preferences seem to be the most relevant option for you.
Refer to the official documentation for an in depth look:
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences

These code samples should help you as well:
To save a value into the Shared Preferences:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int defaultValue = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.saved_high_score_default_key); //set a default/backup option 
int highScore = sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score_key), defaultValue);
```

Make sure to keep the key identical between placing values into the preferences and retrieving.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int defaultValue = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.saved_high_score_default_key);
int highScore = sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score_key), defaultValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

`SharedPreferences` is probably the place to start with this. You can view Android documentation related to it here along with code examples: [Save key-value data](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences)

There are some other options for saving data in an Android app on the left pane of that page, but `SharedPreferences` is probably the most applicable based on your described use case.